# Unable to remove peruser launchd process

Tags: macos, launchd, launchctl

I am constantly getting the following messages in system log:

*com.apple.launchd.peruser.0 (homebrew.mxcl.memcached[PID]) Exited with code : 64
com.apple.launchd.peruser.0 (homebrew.mxcl.memcached) Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds.*

After searching online I learned that it is caused by the process failing to start. And a solution is to unload the plist from launchd with *launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.memcached.plist*, and *launchctl remove homebrew.mxcl.memcached*, which I have done.

Note that the peruser.0 in the messages indicates that it is running 'peruser' for the user root. And I am logged in as root user to unload the homebrew.mxcl.memcached entries and remove the labels in launchd.

I have confirmed with *launchctl list* that memcached is no longer there and I am getting the intended error messages as well when try to unload/remove memcached in launchctl too. I also get '*launchctl stop error: No such process*' when I do *launchctl stop homebrew.mxcl.memcached*. It looks like the memcached plist was successfully deleted from launchctl.

However the process still seems to be loaded at the user level for the root user as the what I did did not stop the messages. When I log off as root and login as another user, the messages stops, and when I log back in as root the messages starts again.

I am very confused on why the process is still triggered for the root user. Since all indications show that the plist was removed from launchd.

Any help/hints would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you run `launchctl` as root, it interacts with the system instance of launchd, rather than the per-user one. As a result, I don't know of a way to use it to manage agents for the root user. But since that agent is getting reloaded every time you log in as root, I'm guessing you have a copy of the .plist file in /var/root/Library/LaunchAgents -- remove that, then log out and back in as root, and it should be gone.

Comment: There was indeed a copy of the plist file in the folder you specified. I have removed it and cleaned it from the trash can. Re-logged in as root and message still persists..with the file gone from the folder.

Comment: Hmm, try rebooting. I've seen some launchd jobs persist between login sessions, and it's possible logging out & in isn't forcing it to fully reload the agent files.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually had to delete the original plist from /Library/LaunchAgents to stop the messages. The file has to be kept off the folder as well becasue when I tried to put it back in and re-login the messages are showing again..

There is probably a way to unload the plist peruser for root user but for now I have to live with just removing the file. Thanks to Gordon for helping!